# Adding a vocal "Ajax Spinner" to a long-running Alexa Response

Tags: asynchronous, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Alexa skill that sometimes takes a while to respond. Sometimes it is running scripts in the background, turning on a TV, connecting a bluetooth device, etc. etc. A successful response can take up to 20+ seconds once all the automation is completed.

On the web, when there is a long-running request, we are used to seeing a progress bar, or at least an animated spinner with a message telling to please wait, or that the processes is underway. I need something similar for Alexa.

I'd like Alexa to respond TWICE to a SINGLE intent, once before the HTTP request is fired, and one once the response has been received. A sample conversation would be:

> [User] : Alexa, tell [app name] to switch to theater mode.
>
> [Alexa] : (Immediately) I'm on it! Hang tight.
>
> (...20 seconds later...)
>
> [Alexa] : Done! Theater mode was successfully activated. Enjoy!

I've got some code running on lambda here: http://jsfiddle.net/9gmszmku/embedded/js/

Excerpt:

```
    // ================ 
    // [TODO] RESPONSE HERE:  Alexa says: "I'm on it" or "hang on one second..." before getting the response from the http request
    // ================ 

    // this request may take many seconds!!!!  Ain't nobody got time for staring at Echo for a response!!!
    var req = http.request(options, (res) => {

      console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
      console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);


      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      var rawData = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);

      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
          var parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
          console.log(parsedData);
          context.succeed(generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse(parsedData.message, true), {}));
        } catch (e) {
          context.succeed(generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse("Error Parsing", true), {}));
        }
      });
```

Basically, I want to have Alexa respond upfront without closing the session, and again once the function is complete.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you can only have one speech output and I don't think you can inject any sort of `wait up one sec` logic into it.  You could work around it by breaking the task up into smaller pieces, chaining them together and having Alexa notify the user at each stage?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could play some music with the [audioplayer](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/reference/audioplayer) interface while your task is working and/or you can inform the user about the long running task with a speech output.